# How to switch between keys and values in python dictionary in place (without changing it's location in memory)

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

i was asked to write a code including a function- reverse_dict_in_place(d)

which switches between keys and values of the inputed dictionary 
without changing the dictionary's location in memory (in place).

however, testing it with id() function shows that all my solutions do change dictionaries memory location..

```
def reverse_dict_in_place(d):
    d={y:x for x,y in d.items()}
    return d
```

Comment: But your code doesn't even attempt to do what is asked; you simply create a new dictionary and return it. Why would you think this would work?

Comment: It's impossible to invert a dictionary, since you can't be sure that there are no duplicate values.

Comment: There's a big difference between "can throw an exception" and "impossible." I think this needs [mcve]. Show a few lines of code that demonstrate id() changing. This is important to establish what it is you want.

Comment: It's entirely possible to reverse the dictionary in place, but what have you tried to maintain the memory location? This looks like a homework question where you just threw up your hands and said "I give up" without *really* trying.  There are lots of in-place methods such as item assignments or `dict.clear()` or `dict.update()`, and it's easy to obtain a copy with `dict.copy()`.  Hopefully that will start you on the right path, just remember to handle duplicate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to current ones which allows values to be same as keys. Works in mostly the same way though, however once again no two values may be the same.

```
def reverse_dict_in_place(d):
    copy = d.copy().items()
    d.clear()
    for k, v in copy:
        d[v] = k
    return d

>>> x = {0: 1, 1: 2}
>>> y = reverse_dict_in_place(x)
>>> id(x) == id(y)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some assumptions for this to work (thanks to all the users who pointed these out):

- There are no duplicate values
- There are no non-hashable values
- There are no values that are also keys

If you're comfortable with those assumption then I think this should work:

```
def reverse_dict_in_place(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        del d[k]
        d[v] = k
    return d
```

Comment: can you demonstrate that this has different behavior regarding "id()" than the code in OP?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, as dictionary changes size during iteration. I posted something similar, but the key-value can modify a key already in the dictionary. Therefore not only must there be no duplicate values, but no duplicates in the set of values and keys

Comment: @KennyOstrom running `id(d) == id(reverse_dict_in_place(d))` will return `True` for my implementation and `False` for the OP's code.

Comment: @NightShade I agree that this would not work if one of the values in the dictionary is also a key in it.

Comment: I would totally advise against mutating during iteration.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues completely agree! As this question seems to be more of a challenge/interview type question, I assumed it can be solved by any (potentially unsafe) means necessary. This should never be used in real code!

Comment: @Glad In this case you may actually get away with it, at least since python 3 something, dicts are ordered by insert order. Just elaborated on a new answer, if you want I can edit yours and ditch mine.

Comment: seems to work! is it possible to run it without changing keys sequence?

Comment: @MarkSchaff since Python 3.7 the keys are ordered by insertion so when we're iterating over them and setting the value as the key - the order should be preserved. In earlier versions of Python keys don't really have an order (unless `OrderedDict` is used) so there's no guarantee on the order you'll get when iterating as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note: @NightShade has posted a similar answer as my below answer, earlier than I posted.

---

You can try this:

```
def reverse_dict_in_place(d):
    d_copy = d.copy()
    d.clear()
    for k in d_copy:
        d[d_copy[k]] = k
```

This would work even if one of the dictionary's values happens to also be a key (as tested out below)

**Testing it out:**

```
my_dict = {1:1, 2:'two', 3:'three'}
reverse_dict_in_place(my_dict)
print (my_dict)
```

**Output:**

> {1: 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [Gad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55338099/3343753) suggestion, you could use dict comprehension:

```py
reversed = {v: k for k, v in d.items()}
```

Where `d` is a dict, and the same assumptions apply:

> - There are no duplicate values
> - There are no non-hashable values
> - There are no values that are also keys

This would not work, without modification, for nested dicts.

Comment: This is the same as what is provided in the question, and points to a new dictionary, hence a different `id` as well

Comment: That is true. I'm afraid python will manage memory for you, that is not a choice. I guess you would need to implement that in C.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
my_dict = {'d': 0, 'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'a': 3}

dict(zip(my_dict.values(),my_dict.keys()))
```

**output:**
{0: 'd', 1: 'c', 2: 'b', 3: 'a'}